# Folders show up miltiple times in PhpStorm project structure

Tags: phpstorm

This is what PhpStorm shows:

[image]

[image]

This is what `ls` says:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  app  .git  .gitignore  .idea  modman  web
```

Why are directories duplicated and what can I do so it doesn't happen? I tried restarting PhpStorm and removing `.idea/workspace.xml`, it doesn't help.

Comment: 2nd screenshot -- why there are empty spaces? Is it done like that by IDE  .. or you have removed duplicate entries yourself?

Comment: @LazyOne That's another view: the first one is "Project", the second one is "Project files". I didn't remove anything, that's how IDE renders it.

Comment: I doubt that it will be the same .. but could be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101953 . In meantime -- have you tried "usual recipe" (`File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart)? Will collapsing root node and then expanding it again will make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this with the following:

- `mv duplicated_directory _bak`;
- Do something with `duplicated_directory` in IDE, e.g. collapse/uncollapse it in project view until it disappears;
- `mv _bak duplicated_directory`;
- Do the same with other directories.